# USE of XAML not related to WPF or silverlight

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, workflow-foundation

I am trying to understand the use of XAML instead using it as markup in creating WPF and silverlight applications. Where else could i use XAML. Please provider all the possible uses of XAML.

Could XAML be used as regular XML to provider mapping and related stuff?

Please provider some links where i could learn about XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This writeup can be helpful:  http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/.  This article describes a way on how XAML can be used as a serialization format not just for a user-interface, but also for other CLR objects.

Comment: Good link it answered my question to good extent. Can XAML be used in any part of .net web application apart from Silverlight and WF.

Comment: Well, as the link says, it can be used to represent other CLR objects.  .NET web apps will certainly be using CLR objects behind the scenes so yes, I believe XAML can also be used on web apps.  Though I must say, I can't see what benefits you'll get if you do.

Answer (score 1):

XAML is used as the serialization mechanism for workflows in Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), see for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/XAML_WF.aspx

Comment: Link was helpful. Can we do more then that like what XML is doing? Now I got it could be used for serialization. Can XAML be used in any part of .net web application apart from WF.

Answer (score 0):

XAML's a fairly efficient XML serialization format with hooks for namespaces and markup extensions.  You don't have to use it purely for WPF applications; as long as the types you're serializing have parameterless constructors you can represent just about any .NET reference type in XAML.

If you're not using markup extensions, it's not really a huge leap past ordinary XML serialization.  But the incremental improvements that it offers are useful enough, and the fact that it's a format supported by VS and WPF and Blend certainly doesn't *hurt*.